# Add a Web Part (zone) outside main content area on SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-part, branding

Is there a way of adding Web Parts outside the main content area?I want to have a image slider outside my main content area and it has to be between the Global navigation and the secondary navigation I created.

Comment: Hi - I have removed the 2010 tag since we prefer to use version tags only when the question is really specific to a SharePoint version. Anyway, I also have posted some notices that come to mind on how you could achieve your goal in the answer below. Fell free to ask for clarification or further details.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you consider to be the content area.

Assuming that you are using the publishing infrastructure (but this explanation could be extended to standard non-publishing pages) your page structure is given by a page layout applied to a master page.

That implies that your layout can only work with the content areas the master page define, and that you can only use web part zones added somewhere on the page by your current page layout.

Since you are asking this question, I assume that your master page / page layouts don't include a web part zone suited to the result that you want to achieve.

That said, you have a set of option

1. if you can, modify your master page or page layout to include a web part zone in the position you need.
2. statically add the web part to the master page: this assume that you are fine displaying the web part everywhere, and that you can edit the master page.
3. workaround the problem by identifying a delegate control that you can use to add a custom control instead of a web part: this will only work if you actually have an appropriate delegate control placeholder on the page.

If anything else fail, <strike>use fire</strike> you can resort to a web part that use jquery to actually add the required dom elements in the required position on the page.